# how get post variable in php?

Tags: java, php, http-post

i am writing a java code that http post with a parameter.that parameter is a long variable that convert to string.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters =new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MAX_ID", String.valueOf(maxNewsId)));
        String result = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(NewsUrl,parameters);
```

and i want write a php code at the server. that code should get that long number and connect to Data base and select rows that have id greater than that parameter.
i write this code but not working. what should i do?

```
  <?php
 $db_host  = "localhost";
 $db_uid  = "**********";
 $db_pass = "**********";
 $db_name  = "**********"; 


 $db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass,$db_name) or die('could not connect'); 
 mysql_select_db($db_name);
 $maxId = $_POST['MAX_ID'];
 mysql_query("set names utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM News where Nid> ".mysql_real_escape_string($maxId);
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[]=$row;

}
print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close();   

?>
```

Comment: try to print and check what is in $_POST varibale . use this on top of the php file <?php echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit();?>

Comment: explain what is not working. What is the error you see?

Check the MAX_ID: 
if (int($_POST['MAX_ID']) == 0) { echo "no variable recieved"; exit();
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes about your code:

First... please don't use mysql_query anymore. Use mysqli_query or PDO. In newer PHP versions mysql_xxx is deprecated and you should use the alternative.

Second... your code is very susceptible to attack. When you use a POST or GET variable you should check if it does not contain harmful code. If your `MAX_ID` could only be a number i would suggest the following (note the `intval`-part):

```
$maxId = 0;
if (isset($_POST['MAX_ID'])) $maxId = intval($_POST['MAX_ID']);
```

It also checks if MAX_ID is not set (if so your $max_id is 0) and $maxId could only result in a number.

And last... because with above $maxId could only result in a number you don't need the mysql_real_escape_string. So this would be enough:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM News where Nid > ".$maxId;
```

(please note the warning at the top of the [manual of this function](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) about mysql_xxx being deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

if you want greated than: you should change the **"<"** see in bold

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM News WHERE Nid < ".mysql_real_escape_string($maxId);
```